# How to increase amplitude in given oscillator circuit?

Tags: oscillator

I am building a water atomizer using 1.65MHz piezoelectric transducers by this circuit. I am able to get desired frequency and am able to have water vibrating but unable to  atomized it. I think amplitude of waves is not high enough as it is withdrawing 0.2 amp only. Can someone help me increase power of this oscillator ?? [image]

Edit :- I have updated circuit. Earlier I forgot to mention inductance connected to emmitter.

Comment: have you tried a darlington? THis will   lower the emitter impedance.

Comment: I don't think this circuit can work, as there is no DC path for emitter current.

Comment: Peter Bennett I have added inductance between emitter and negative terminal. Earlier I forgot to draw it here. Please see if now it's power/amplitude may be increased. Please suggest someway to increase amplitude.

Comment: Add a PI CLC or LCL resonator to step up the voltage (and power) to the piezo.

Comment: Hi guys I am able to generate good water atomization. I had to use 22uH inductor and 2A,  12v-0-12v power supply with voltage multiplication using 2 4700uF capacitors in series with half wave rectifier across them.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this video by Big Clive where he reverse engineers a water atomizer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DabnOLtLFnc

At [13 minutes into the video](https://youtu.be/DabnOLtLFnc?t=769) he shows the schematic:

[image]

Note how it uses a **transformer** to make a high voltage. This is needed because the transducer has a **very high impedance** meaning it requires a **high voltage** at a **low current** in order for any power to be transferred to it.